# Passport Authenticate POST Request Timing out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am using passport with Express 4 to create local authentication for a MEAN stack application I am creating.

I am able to create new users in a POST request without a problem, but when I try to authenticate a user session, it waits 120000ms before finishing the POST request and no session is created.

The authenticate method was working before, but then randomly started taking 120000ms to complete. I cleared my changes and went through the same process I did before and I still have the same problem. Could there be some sort of cache that needs to be cleared or some log that I can look at?

Notes: I am using passports mongoose package to persist data. I have no problem accessing the mongodb server, so there must be an issue with node, express, angular or passport.

Comment: I should note that the authenticate method only times out when the credentials are correct. When they are incorrect, the POST request immediately returns a 401 error.

Comment: Would you be able to edit the post and include relevant code? The express post route for example